# accepts_nested_attributes_for not allowing updating multiple child records where a uniqueness validation exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I have the following structure:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :devices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :devices, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**models/device.rb**

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :instance, :model_number, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  validates :instance, uniqueness: {scope: :user_id}
end
```

The user form has nested fields for devices.

Assume the following records exist:

```
User (1)
Device (1), instance: 1, user_id: 1
Device (2), instance: 2, user_id: 1
```

I want to go to the user edit form, and swap the instance numbers on the two devices. The problem is that with the existing set up, the first device goes through the update process and when it reaches validations it fails because there's already a device with the instance number I've tried to assign it, due to the updates happening sequentially.

What can I do to stop these validations from being ignorant to that I'm trying to update multiple records at the same time which would end up with the validations passing?